# How do I keep the scrollview where it was last scrolled?

Tags: xcode, scrollview

I have a scroll view with a list of items. Let's say I click one of the item at the bottom, that item takes me to a different page. When I go back to the page with the scroll view, the scroll view is back at the top.

What can I do so that the scroll view stays where it was last scrolled to?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t used this by myself, but it may help:
A `UIScrollView` has a feature called *State Preservation*. The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview) say:

> If you assign a value to this view’s `restorationIdentifier` property,
>   it attempts to preserve its scrolling-related information between app
>   launches. Specifically, the values of the `zoomScale`, `contentInset`, and
>   `contentOffset` properties are preserved. During restoration, the scroll
>   view restores these values so that the content appears scrolled to the
>   same position as before.

I don’t know if this also works when you leave the scroll view controller, and re-instantiate it later. Just try!